# ROR: How to render data to files which are in public directory

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, calendar

I am using jQuery calender to show events based on dates in my ruby on rails application.
And in calender plugin's  js file it requires the my events.json file should be public directory for the application.
The events.json contains the records for dates which I want to mark on calendar.
Is there ant way to render data from controller to files kept in applications public directory or can how can I access the events.json from my calendar view.

My app.js file for calender is like, and it is in assets directory:

```
(function($) {

    "use strict";

    var options = {
        events_source: 'events.json',
        view: 'month',
        tmpl_path: 'tmpls/',
        tmpl_cache: false,
        day: 'now',
        onAfterEventsLoad: function(events) {
            if(!events) {
                return;
            }
            var list = $('#eventlist');
            list.html('');

            $.each(events, function(key, val) {
                $(document.createElement('li'))
                    .html('<a href="' + val.url + '">' + val.title + '</a>')
                    .appendTo(list);
            });
        },
        onAfterViewLoad: function(view) {
            $('.page-header h3').text(this.getTitle());
            $('.btn-group button').removeClass('active');
            $('button[data-calendar-view="' + view + '"]').addClass('active');
        },
        classes: {
            months: {
                general: 'label'
            }
        }
    };

    var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar(options);

    $('.btn-group button[data-calendar-nav]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.click(function() {
            calendar.navigate($this.data('calendar-nav'));
        });
    });

    $('.btn-group button[data-calendar-view]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.click(function() {
            calendar.view($this.data('calendar-view'));
        });
    });

    $('#first_day').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        value = value.length ? parseInt(value) : null;
        calendar.setOptions({first_day: value});
        calendar.view();
    });

    $('#language').change(function(){
        calendar.setLanguage($(this).val());
        calendar.view();
    });

    $('#events-in-modal').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val() : null;
        calendar.setOptions({modal: val});
    });
    $('#events-modal .modal-header, #events-modal .modal-footer').click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

And my events.json is like:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "293",
            "title": "This is warning class event with very long title to check how it fits to evet in day view",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-warning",
            "start": "1400148932",
            "end":   "1400199999"
        },
        {
            "id": "256",
            "title": "Event that ends on timeline",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-warning",
            "start": "1363155300000",
            "end":   "1363227600000"
        },
        {
            "id": "276",
            "title": "Short day event",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-success",
            "start": "1363245600000",
            "end":   "1363252200000"
        },
        {
            "id": "294",
            "title": "This is information class ",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-info",
            "start": "1363111200000",
            "end":   "1363284086400"
        },
        {
            "id": "297",
            "title": "This is success event",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-success",
            "start": "1363234500000",
            "end":   "1363284062400"
        },
        {
            "id": "54",
            "title": "This is simple event",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "",
            "start": "1363712400000",
            "end":   "1363716086400"
        },
        {
            "id": "532",
            "title": "This is inverse event",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-inverse",
            "start": "1364407200000",
            "end":   "1364493686400"
        },
        {
            "id": "548",
            "title": "This is special event",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-special",
            "start": "1363197600000",
            "end":   "1363629686400"
        },
        {
            "id": "295",
            "title": "Event 3",
            "url": "javascript:void()",
            "class": "event-important",
            "start": "1364320800000",
            "end":   "1364407286400"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: how about `events_source: '../my_controller/events.json'`?

Comment: it is not woking..@ Uri Agassi

Answer (score 0):

Set the source of your calendar to the route for a json view of your calendar. So you use the JSON rendering option in rails and have a route set up like `/calendar/events/json` for it, check that returns the data in the format you expect and then set that url as the `events_source` property of your JQuery calendar.

You can see how set up JSON rendering in Rails from [Section 2.2.9 here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) - it is a very simple process. Then you just need to link to your controller.

Alternatively you can simply output the json as a JavaScript literal in the same view that the Calendar control is in, so it is built into that request. I think that would be a little less flexible, though.

Comment: Why do you want to render from the controller into a public file? What your calendar needs is the data in .json format. What your application can provide is the data in .json format. So point the javascript at the application. There is no difference from the calendar whether it points at `/assets/file.js` or `/controller/calendar/json` as long as the data is correct.

Comment: you mean I need to include the calender source from my view folder.?

Comment: Exactly, but I don't think you need a view if you are showing it as `json` because that is simply a case of serialising the objects. I will add a link to the answer here.

Comment: But it is not working if I include the calendar source from the view folder ?

Comment: Now the calender source is working from my view folder. But the it requires my json file in the public directory.

Comment: How can I change the path for that ?

Comment: Just change `events_source: 'events.json',` to `events_source: '/controller/json_view',` - obviously changing the path to whatever you have set up to serve up the json data- and you should be away.